# How to use a Space through HTML in a groovy script

Tags: html, groovy, progress-bar, vaadin

how can i give a space at the start of the caption for a vaadin progress-bar through html,
I have the following code which is in groovy script, vaadin-version 7-6.3.

```
_progressbar().setCaptionAsHtml(true);
_progressbar()().setCaption("&nbsp SollStent ="+ equipment.getTotalCount());
```

**&nbsp** did not give the results i needed. 
I needed my caption to be bold and to set the caption to the right of the progress-bar instead left. By default the caption of the progress bar starts at the start, how can i change it to the right ? and also if i want to set the caption under a progress-bar instead of top. How can i achieve it. I have tried using ***setCaptionAsHtml*** giving the spaces and move the caption to right. Is there any other way. Did not find more in altering the vaadin progress-bar. Thank you very much.

Comment: I would try to achieve that with CSS - but positioning the cation to the right seems hard or impossible… Put the progressbar and a label with the caption into a horizontal layout.

Comment: I agree with @SaschaFrinken. For the space, I think the semi-colon delimiter is missing. Try `&nbsp;`.

Comment: Thank you @SaschaFrinken

Comment: @user9630935 If you came up with a solution you can share it with the StackOverflow community by answering your own question below.